# Chemical oxygen generator

Tags: chemical-engineering

[image][image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReyoV.png)enter image description here[image][image][image][image]

Why airborne chemical oxygen generator has shelf life? What causes deterioration of the generator which are not used during long time?
The generator comprises Sodium Chlorate (NaClO3) mixed with <5% Barium Peroxide (BaO2) and <1% Potassium Perchlorate (KClO4). The aforesaid mixture is activated by the application of heat, which is normally generated by a mixture of lead styphnate and tetracene which itself is activated by a small explosive charge.

[image]

Comment: Which one? what chemicals? How is it sealed?

Comment: Airborne chemical generator comprises sodium chlorate mixed with 5% barium peroxide and less than 1% potassium perchlorate

Comment: Add that info to your question to improve it, also important info gets lost in comments.

Comment: Supposing you needed a chemical reaction to happen, and wanted to make happen only on demand, how willing would you be to allow the reverse reaction to occur when you did not need it? That is a typical price.  (Might be better suited to the Chem exchange(s))

Answer (score 0):

It *probably* has to do with moisture diffusion into the contents of the oxygen generator, which might trigger degradation of those chemicals.